# Unable to delete a DataBricks table: Container xxx in account yyy.blob.core.windows.net not found

Tags: hive, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-storage-account

I have a series of parquet files in different folders on an Azure Storage Account Container.
I can expose them all as SQL tables with command like:

```
create table table_name
using parquet
location 'wasbs://mycontainer@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/folder_or_parquet_files'
```

And all is fine. However I want to drop them all and they all drop except one, which gives me:

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
MetaException(message:Got exception: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException
shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Container mycontainer in account
mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net not found,and we can't create it using 
anoynomous credentials, and no credentials found for them in the configuration.)
```

Obviously mystorageaccount and mycontainer are in to replace my real values, and creating / droping other folders of parquet files in that container / storage account works fine.
It's just one table seems a little messed up.

How can I get rid of this broken table, please?

Comment: looks like there is no credentials for that specific blog storage account.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid it's not that, as as I mention all others in the same container, schema everything all drop ok, just this one that doesn't :(